# Почему this может быть undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```js
'use strict'
class A {
 constructor(){}
 Do(){
  alert(this)
 }
}
let a = new A()
a.Do()
let b = a.Do
b()
```

Почему во втором вызове выводится undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что используется "use strict"

При использовании "use strict" - `this` по умолчания - `undefined`

В первом вызове `this` - указывает на объект.

Но после получения ссылки на функцию и выполнения

```
let b = a.Do;
b();
```

Контекст меняется на глобальный объект, либо, при использовании "use strict" на *undefined*

Кроме того, в [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Strict_mode)

> Тело определения класса, и `class expressions` выполняются в strict mode.

Comment: Не понимаю. Ну да, функция вызывается не от имени обьекта, но ведь она является его прототипом. Извините, но в JavaScript я новичок, и это поведение кажется мне крайне странным.

Comment: @Alster, смиритесь :-) значение `this` зависит от того как именно вызвали функцию